# Heroku cannot serve files from bower_components

Tags: node.js, heroku, bower

I'm having trouble getting Heroku to find resources in the `bower_components` folder, but the site works fine on `localhost`.

I created an express-node.js site. The structure of the site looks like this.

```
site
-> bower_components
--> jquery
---> dist
----> jquery.min.js
-> Other folders
-> app.js
```

I've made the `bower_components` folder public like this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
```

To retrieve the `jquery` file, I've specified it like so in the html

`<script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Why does this work on `localhost` but not when I deploy it to Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by putting `postinstall` into `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **bower** in the package.json file and include post-install script

```
 "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  },
```

If you dont have bower in package.json file, again it will result in an error.